# Extract and process information between two strings, being these strings repeated multiple times along the file

Tags: python, list, parsing, file-io, text-extraction

I have a file with this structure:

```
 LATTICE PARAMETERS (ANGSTROMS AND DEGREES) - BOHR = 0.5291772083 ANGSTROM
 PRIMITIVE CELL - CENTRING CODE 7/0 VOLUME=   122.771603 - DENSITY  2.704 g/cm^3
         A              B              C           ALPHA      BETA       GAMMA
     6.32540491     6.32540491     6.32540491    46.774144  46.774144  46.774144
 *******************************************************************************
 ATOMS IN THE ASYMMETRIC UNIT    3 - ATOMS IN THE UNIT CELL:   10
     ATOM                 X/A                 Y/B                 Z/C
 *******************************************************************************
      1 T  20 CA    0.000000000000E+00  0.000000000000E+00  0.000000000000E+00
      2 F  20 CA   -5.000000000000E-01 -5.000000000000E-01 -5.000000000000E-01
      3 T   6 C     2.500000000000E-01  2.500000000000E-01  2.500000000000E-01
      4 F   6 C    -2.500000000000E-01 -2.500000000000E-01 -2.500000000000E-01
      5 T   8 O    -4.912600492192E-01 -8.739950780750E-03  2.500000000000E-01
      6 F   8 O     2.500000000000E-01 -4.912600492193E-01 -8.739950780750E-03
      7 F   8 O    -8.739950780750E-03  2.500000000000E-01 -4.912600492193E-01
      8 F   8 O     4.912600492193E-01  8.739950780750E-03 -2.500000000000E-01
      9 F   8 O    -2.500000000000E-01  4.912600492193E-01  8.739950780750E-03
     10 F   8 O     8.739950780750E-03 -2.500000000000E-01  4.912600492193E-01

 TRANSFORMATION MATRIX PRIMITIVE-CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC CELL
  1.0000  0.0000  1.0000 -1.0000  1.0000  1.0000  0.0000 -1.0000  1.0000

 *******************************************************************************
 CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC CELL (VOLUME=        368.31480902)
         A              B              C           ALPHA      BETA       GAMMA
     5.02162261     5.02162261    16.86554607    90.000000  90.000000 120.000000

 COORDINATES IN THE CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC CELL
     ATOM                 X/A                 Y/B                 Z/C
 *******************************************************************************
      1 T  20 CA    0.000000000000E+00  0.000000000000E+00  0.000000000000E+00
      2 F  20 CA    0.000000000000E+00  0.000000000000E+00 -5.000000000000E-01
      3 T   6 C     3.333333333333E-01 -3.333333333333E-01 -8.333333333333E-02
      4 F   6 C    -3.333333333333E-01  3.333333333333E-01  8.333333333333E-02
      5 T   8 O    -4.079267158859E-01 -3.333333333333E-01 -8.333333333333E-02
      6 F   8 O     3.333333333333E-01 -7.459338255258E-02 -8.333333333333E-02
      7 F   8 O     7.459338255258E-02  4.079267158859E-01 -8.333333333333E-02
      8 F   8 O     4.079267158859E-01  3.333333333333E-01  8.333333333333E-02
      9 F   8 O    -3.333333333333E-01  7.459338255258E-02  8.333333333333E-02
     10 F   8 O    -7.459338255258E-02 -4.079267158859E-01  8.333333333333E-02

 T = ATOM BELONGING TO THE ASYMMETRIC UNIT


more lines
more lines
more lines

 FINAL OPTIMIZED GEOMETRY - DIMENSIONALITY OF THE SYSTEM      3
 (NON PERIODIC DIRECTION: LATTICE PARAMETER FORMALLY SET TO 500)
 *******************************************************************************
 LATTICE PARAMETERS (ANGSTROMS AND DEGREES) - BOHR = 0.5291772083 ANGSTROM
 PRIMITIVE CELL - CENTRING CODE 7/0 VOLUME=   119.823364 - DENSITY  2.770 g/cm^3
         A              B              C           ALPHA      BETA       GAMMA
     6.28373604     6.28373604     6.28373604    46.646397  46.646397  46.646397
 *******************************************************************************
 ATOMS IN THE ASYMMETRIC UNIT    3 - ATOMS IN THE UNIT CELL:   10
     ATOM                 X/A                 Y/B                 Z/C
 *******************************************************************************
      1 T  20 CA    0.000000000000E+00  0.000000000000E+00  0.000000000000E+00
      2 F  20 CA   -5.000000000000E-01 -5.000000000000E-01 -5.000000000000E-01
      3 T   6 C     2.500000000000E-01  2.500000000000E-01  2.500000000000E-01
      4 F   6 C    -2.500000000000E-01 -2.500000000000E-01 -2.500000000000E-01
      5 T   8 O    -4.924094276183E-01 -7.590572381674E-03  2.500000000000E-01
      6 F   8 O     2.500000000000E-01 -4.924094276183E-01 -7.590572381674E-03
      7 F   8 O    -7.590572381674E-03  2.500000000000E-01 -4.924094276183E-01
      8 F   8 O     4.924094276183E-01  7.590572381674E-03 -2.500000000000E-01
      9 F   8 O    -2.500000000000E-01  4.924094276183E-01  7.590572381674E-03
     10 F   8 O     7.590572381674E-03 -2.500000000000E-01  4.924094276183E-01

 TRANSFORMATION MATRIX PRIMITIVE-CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC CELL
  1.0000  0.0000  1.0000 -1.0000  1.0000  1.0000  0.0000 -1.0000  1.0000

 *******************************************************************************
 CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC CELL (VOLUME=        359.47009054)
         A              B              C           ALPHA      BETA       GAMMA
     4.97568007     4.97568007    16.76591397    90.000000  90.000000 120.000000

 COORDINATES IN THE CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC CELL
     ATOM                 X/A                 Y/B                 Z/C
 *******************************************************************************
      1 T  20 CA    0.000000000000E+00  0.000000000000E+00  0.000000000000E+00
      2 F  20 CA   -5.491739570355E-17 -2.745869785177E-17 -5.000000000000E-01
      3 T   6 C     3.333333333333E-01 -3.333333333333E-01 -8.333333333333E-02
      4 F   6 C    -3.333333333333E-01  3.333333333333E-01  8.333333333333E-02
      5 T   8 O    -4.090760942850E-01 -3.333333333333E-01 -8.333333333333E-02
      6 F   8 O     3.333333333333E-01 -7.574276095166E-02 -8.333333333333E-02
      7 F   8 O     7.574276095166E-02  4.090760942850E-01 -8.333333333333E-02
      8 F   8 O     4.090760942850E-01  3.333333333333E-01  8.333333333333E-02
      9 F   8 O    -3.333333333333E-01  7.574276095166E-02  8.333333333333E-02
     10 F   8 O    -7.574276095166E-02 -4.090760942850E-01  8.333333333333E-02

 T = ATOM BELONGING TO THE ASYMMETRIC UNIT
 INFORMATION **** fort.34 **** GEOMETRY OUTPUT FILE

more lines
more lines
more lines

 FINAL OPTIMIZED GEOMETRY - DIMENSIONALITY OF THE SYSTEM      3
 (NON PERIODIC DIRECTION: LATTICE PARAMETER FORMALLY SET TO 500)
 *******************************************************************************
 LATTICE PARAMETERS (ANGSTROMS AND DEGREES) - BOHR = 0.5291772083 ANGSTROM
 PRIMITIVE CELL - CENTRING CODE 7/0 VOLUME=   121.143469 - DENSITY  2.740 g/cm^3
         A              B              C           ALPHA      BETA       GAMMA
     6.32229536     6.32229536     6.32229536    46.436583  46.436583  46.436583
 *******************************************************************************
 ATOMS IN THE ASYMMETRIC UNIT    3 - ATOMS IN THE UNIT CELL:   10
     ATOM                 X/A                 Y/B                 Z/C
 *******************************************************************************
      1 T  20 CA    0.000000000000E+00  0.000000000000E+00  0.000000000000E+00
      2 F  20 CA    5.000000000000E-01 -5.000000000000E-01 -5.000000000000E-01
      3 T   6 C     2.500000000000E-01  2.500000000000E-01  2.500000000000E-01
      4 F   6 C    -2.500000000000E-01 -2.500000000000E-01 -2.500000000000E-01
      5 T   8 O    -4.927088991116E-01 -7.291100888437E-03  2.500000000000E-01
      6 F   8 O     2.500000000000E-01 -4.927088991116E-01 -7.291100888437E-03
      7 F   8 O    -7.291100888437E-03  2.500000000000E-01 -4.927088991116E-01
      8 F   8 O     4.927088991116E-01  7.291100888437E-03 -2.500000000000E-01
      9 F   8 O    -2.500000000000E-01  4.927088991116E-01  7.291100888437E-03
     10 F   8 O     7.291100888437E-03 -2.500000000000E-01  4.927088991116E-01

 TRANSFORMATION MATRIX PRIMITIVE-CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC CELL
  1.0000  0.0000  1.0000 -1.0000  1.0000  1.0000  0.0000 -1.0000  1.0000

 *******************************************************************************
 CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC CELL (VOLUME=        363.43040599)
         A              B              C           ALPHA      BETA       GAMMA
     4.98494429     4.98494429    16.88768068    90.000000  90.000000 120.000000

 COORDINATES IN THE CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC CELL
     ATOM                 X/A                 Y/B                 Z/C
 *******************************************************************************
      1 T  20 CA    0.000000000000E+00  0.000000000000E+00  0.000000000000E+00
      2 F  20 CA   -5.471726358381E-17 -2.735863179191E-17 -5.000000000000E-01
      3 T   6 C     3.333333333333E-01 -3.333333333333E-01 -8.333333333333E-02
      4 F   6 C    -3.333333333333E-01  3.333333333333E-01  8.333333333333E-02
      5 T   8 O    -4.093755657782E-01 -3.333333333333E-01 -8.333333333333E-02
      6 F   8 O     3.333333333333E-01 -7.604223244490E-02 -8.333333333333E-02
      7 F   8 O     7.604223244490E-02  4.093755657782E-01 -8.333333333333E-02
      8 F   8 O     4.093755657782E-01  3.333333333333E-01  8.333333333333E-02
      9 F   8 O    -3.333333333333E-01  7.604223244490E-02  8.333333333333E-02
     10 F   8 O    -7.604223244490E-02 -4.093755657782E-01  8.333333333333E-02

 T = ATOM BELONGING TO THE ASYMMETRIC UNIT
 INFORMATION **** fort.34 **** GEOMETRY OUTPUT FILE

more lines
more lines
more lines
```

I would like to extract `CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC CELL`'s information; but only the one that comes from a `FINAL OPTIMIZED GEOMETRY`.

The following 3 matches:

```
initial_pattern = '^ FINAL OPTIMIZED GEOMETRY - DIMENSIONALITY OF THE SYSTEM      3$'
middle_pattern = '^ CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC CELL '
end_pattern = '^ T = ATOM BELONGING TO THE ASYMMETRIC UNIT$'
```

allow to search for the information.

Firstly, I define a flag `passed_mid_point = False`,

and then the following part of the program extracts the `VOLUME` of the `FINAL OPTIMIZED GEOMETRY`'s `CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC CELL`:

```
VOLUMES = []
with open('g.out') as file:
    passed_mid_point = False
    for line in file:
        if re.match(initial_pattern, line):
            passed_mid_point = False
            print file.next()
            print file.next()
            print file.next()

            volume_line = file.next()
            print volume_line
            aux = volume_line.split()
            each_volume = aux[7]
            print each_volume
            VOLUMES.append(each_volume)
print 'VOLUMES = ', VOLUMES
```

which is correct, because `VOLUMES =  ['119.823364', '121.143469']`. Note that the initial `122.771603` (see original file) is not gathered in the list, as expected.

When extracting the `A` and `C` (in my program, `P0` and `P1`), parameters of the `FINAL OPTIMIZED GEOMETRY`'s `CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC CELL`, together with the coordinates:

```
        if re.match(middle_pattern, line):
            passed_mid_point = True

            print line

            print file.next()
            parameters_line = file.next()
            aux = parameters_line.split()
            p0 = aux[0]
            p1 = aux[1]
            p2 = aux[2]
            p3 = aux[3]
            p4 = aux[4]
            p5 = aux[5] # 

            print p0
            print p2

            P0.append(p0)
            P2.append(p2)

            print file.next()
            print file.next()
            print file.next()
            print file.next()

        if re.match(end_pattern, line):
            passed_mid_point = False

        elif passed_mid_point:
            # parse the coordinates
            print 'line2 =', line
            terms = line.split()
            print 'terms =', terms
#           print 'terms[1] =', terms[1]

            if terms and terms[1] == 'T':
                print terms[1]
                atomic_number = terms[2]
                print 'atomic_number = ', atomic_number
                ATOMIC_NUMBERS.append(atomic_number)

                x = terms[4]
                print 'x =', x
                Xs.append(x)

                y = terms[5]
                print 'y = ', y
                Ys.append(y)

                z = terms[6]
                print 'z = ', z
                Zs.append(z)

print 'VOLUMES = ', VOLUMES
print 'P0 = ', P0
print 'P2 = ', P2
print 'Xs = ', Xs
print 'Ys = ', Ys
print 'Zs = ', Zs
print 'ATOMIC_NUMBERS = ', ATOMIC_NUMBERS
```

The result is the following:

```
P0 =  ['5.02162261', '4.97568007', '4.98494429']
```

which is wrong, because `5.02162261` does not come from a `FINAL OPTIMIZED GEOMETRY` (see file).

Also the coordinates are wrong:

```
Xs =  ['0.000000000000E+00', '3.333333333333E-01', '-4.079267158859E-01', '0.000000000000E+00', '3.333333333333E-01', '-4.090760942850E-01', '0.000000000000E+00', '3.333333333333E-01', '-4.093755657782E-01']
Ys =  ['0.000000000000E+00', '-3.333333333333E-01', '-3.333333333333E-01', '0.000000000000E+00', '-3.333333333333E-01', '-3.333333333333E-01', '0.000000000000E+00', '-3.333333333333E-01', '-3.333333333333E-01']
Zs =  ['0.000000000000E+00', '-8.333333333333E-02', '-8.333333333333E-02', '0.000000000000E+00', '-8.333333333333E-02', '-8.333333333333E-02', '0.000000000000E+00', '-8.333333333333E-02', '-8.333333333333E-02']
ATOMIC_NUMBERS =  ['20', '6', '8', '20', '6', '8', '20', '6', '8']
```

This would be the desired result:

```
VOLUMES =  ['119.823364', '121.143469']
P0 = ['4.97568007', '4.98494429']
P1 = [16.76591397, '16.88768068']
Xs =  ['0.000000000000E+00', '3.333333333333E-01', '-4.090760942850E-01', '0.000000000000E+00', '3.333333333333E-01', '-4.093755657782E-01']
Ys =  ['0.000000000000E+00', '-3.333333333333E-01', '-3.333333333333E-01', '0.000000000000E+00', '-3.333333333333E-01', '-3.333333333333E-01']
Zs =  ['0.000000000000E+00', '-8.333333333333E-02', '-8.333333333333E-02', '0.000000000000E+00', '-8.333333333333E-02', '-8.333333333333E-02']
ATOMIC_NUMBERS =  ['20', '6', '8', '20', '6', '8']
```

I would appreciate if you could help me

**Entire code:**

```
import sys
import re
import os

initial_pattern = '^ FINAL OPTIMIZED GEOMETRY - DIMENSIONALITY OF THE SYSTEM      3$'
middle_pattern = '^ CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC CELL '
end_pattern = '^ T = ATOM BELONGING TO THE ASYMMETRIC UNIT$'

global N_atom_irreducible_unit
N_atom_irreducible_unit = 3

VOLUMES = []
P0 = []
P2 = []
ATOMIC_NUMBERS = []
Xs = []
Ys = []
Zs = []

with open('g.out') as file:
    passed_mid_point = False
    for line in file:
        if re.match(initial_pattern, line):
            passed_mid_point = False
            print file.next()
            print file.next()
            print file.next()

            volume_line = file.next()
            print volume_line
            aux = volume_line.split()
            each_volume = aux[7]
            print each_volume
            VOLUMES.append(each_volume)

        if re.match(middle_pattern, line):
            passed_mid_point = True

            print line

            print file.next()
            parameters_line = file.next()
            aux = parameters_line.split()
            p0 = aux[0]
            p1 = aux[1]
            p2 = aux[2]
            p3 = aux[3]
            p4 = aux[4]
            p5 = aux[5] # 

            print p0
            print p2

            P0.append(p0)
            P2.append(p2)

            print file.next()
            print file.next()
            print file.next()
            print file.next()

        if re.match(end_pattern, line):
            passed_mid_point = False

        elif passed_mid_point:
            # parse the coordinates
            print 'line2 =', line
            terms = line.split()
            print 'terms =', terms
#           print 'terms[1] =', terms[1]

            if terms and terms[1] == 'T':
                print terms[1]
                atomic_number = terms[2]
                print 'atomic_number = ', atomic_number
                ATOMIC_NUMBERS.append(atomic_number)

                x = terms[4]
                print 'x =', x
                Xs.append(x)

                y = terms[5]
                print 'y = ', y
                Ys.append(y)

                z = terms[6]
                print 'z = ', z
                Zs.append(z)

print 'VOLUMES = ', VOLUMES
print 'P0 = ', P0
print 'P2 = ', P2
print 'Xs = ', Xs
print 'Ys = ', Ys
print 'Zs = ', Zs
print 'ATOMIC_NUMBERS = ', ATOMIC_NUMBERS
```

Comment: are you sure your desired result is correct, since you mention the same number which you designate as being wrong just above in it (4.98494429)?

Comment: @Bart Van Loon  Thank you very much for your comment, I made a typo. See edited post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a simplified version of your script, which seems to work. I hope this can count as a starting point for your final script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

VOLUMES = []
P0 = []
P2 = []
ATOMIC_NUMBERS = []
Xs = []
Ys = []
Zs = []

with open('g.out') as gout:
    final_optimized_geometry = False
    for line in gout:
        if 'FINAL OPTIMIZED GEOMETRY' in line:
            final_optimized_geometry = True
        elif 'PRIMITIVE CELL' in line:
            if not final_optimized_geometry:
                continue
            volume = line.split()[7]
            VOLUMES.append(volume)
        elif 'CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC CELL (VOLUME=' in line:
            if not final_optimized_geometry:
                continue
            gout.readline()
            line = gout.readline()
            p0, p2 = line.split()[0:3:2]

            P0.append(p0)
            P2.append(p2)
        elif 'COORDINATES IN THE CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC CELL' in line:
            if not final_optimized_geometry:
                continue
            gout.readline()
            gout.readline()
            while 'T = ATOM BELONGING TO THE ASYMMETRIC UNIT' not in line:
                line = gout.readline()
                atomdata = line.split()
                if not atomdata or atomdata[1] != 'T':
                    continue
                atomicnumber = atomdata[2]
                x, y, z = atomdata[4:7]
                ATOMIC_NUMBERS.append(atomicnumber)
                Xs.append(x)
                Ys.append(y)
                Zs.append(z)
            final_optimized_geometry = False


print(VOLUMES)
print(P0)
print(P2)
print(ATOMIC_NUMBERS)
print(Xs)
print(Ys)
print(Zs)
```

This generates the following output:

```
['119.823364', '121.143469']
['4.97568007', '4.98494429']
['16.76591397', '16.88768068']
['20', '6', '8', '20', '6', '8']
['0.000000000000E+00', '3.333333333333E-01', '-4.090760942850E-01', '0.000000000000E+00', '3.333333333333E-01', '-4.093755657782E-01']
['0.000000000000E+00', '-3.333333333333E-01', '-3.333333333333E-01', '0.000000000000E+00', '-3.333333333333E-01', '-3.333333333333E-01']
['0.000000000000E+00', '-8.333333333333E-02', '-8.333333333333E-02', '0.000000000000E+00', '-8.333333333333E-02', '-8.333333333333E-02']
```

In fact it's a very simple finite state machine with only two states. Warning: it will not work if there are multiple crystallographic cells in one final optimized geometry. In that case it will only capture the first cell's information.

The code also makes other assumptions about the file, which perhaps need to be verified of course.

I avoided the use of regular expressions.

This code will only run in Python 3 (tested against Python 3.6.2). Python 2.7 will choke on using `readline()` inside the file iteration block (which kind of makes sense, but it's great to see Python 3 is okay with it). We are using `readline()` as a little hack to skip lines from the input file we know for certain have to be skipped, without going through the whole loop again (which would require more flag variables).

By the way, if your sole task is to parse text files, it might be interesting to check out dedicated languages, such as [Lex](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/) for example. Also, Perl was designed for doing things like this, more than Python was.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your code is not gathering the correct volumes, i.e. `359.47009054` vs `119.823364` (see desired result in the post). In addition, for the extraction of `ATOMIC NUMBERS`, `Xs`, `Ys` and `Zs` you need some sort of third match, i.e. `end_pattern` (see post) to say until which point these 4 lists should be filled with information

Comment: My code is about to achieve the correct thing, but `P0`, `P1`, `ATOMIC NUMBERS`, `Xs`, `Ys` and `Zs` are gathering also the info from the "non-final optimized crystallographic cell", where they should not, and I don't know where is the problem

Comment: Aren't the volumes 121.143469 and 122.771603 from primitive cells instead of from crystallographic cells?

Sorry if I'm mistaken, I'm just trying to interpret the `g.out` file without knowing anything of it's background.

Comment: I updated the code in my answer to include the capturing of the coordinates and the atomic numbers. I hope I'm getting your question right.

Comment: `Aren't the volumes 121.143469 and 122.771603 from primitive cells instead of from crystallographic cells?` Yes. `VOLUMES` have to be from the "Final optimized primitive cell". `P0`, `P1`, `ATOMIC NUMBERS`, `Xs`, `Ys` and `Zs` have to be from the "Final optimized crystallographic cell". This is what is shown in the desired result in the post. No problem, I agree this might be confusing and appreciate very much your effort.

Comment: `I updated the code in my answer to include the capturing of the coordinates and the atomic numbers. ` Your approach is not appropiate, because this will gather until atom 10. For another compound and another `g.out`, the list of atoms can change, and this is no longer valid. That is why I used a  third match, i.e. `end_pattern` to be the string `T = ATOM BELONGING TO THE ASYMMETRIC UNIT`, =>  This will specify until which point these 4 lists (`P0`, `P1`, `ATOMIC NUMBERS`, `Xs`, `Ys` and `Zs`) should be filled with info. Please see the **Entire code:** in the post

Comment: In addition, your code produces this error: `ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data` in `line 19`. When you said "This generates the following output:", How did you then obtain that result? Thanks

Comment: I guess this last error might be because of mismatching Python versions? I'm using Python 3.6.2.

For the end_pattern, I believe this is a simple fix in the line `if not atomdata:` or in the while conditional: you have to break the inner loop when `'T = ATOM BELONGING TO THE ASYMMETRIC UNIT' in line`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I updated the code once more for (a) getting the primitive cell volumes, (b) capturing all atom data. I also confirmed that the error you are getting is due to a limitation in Python 2. If it's possible for you, it might be a good idea to move to Python 3 altogether? Best of luck!

Comment: You are right, with Python 2.7 you would have to use `gout.next()` instead of `gout.readline()`. This approach is great, thank you very much. I have written a simplification (see below)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all @Bart Van Loon's help, a simpler version of the code would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

global N_atom_irreducible_unit
N_atom_irreducible_unit = 3

filename = 'g.out'

VOLUMES = []
P0 = []
P2 = []
ATOMIC_NUMBERS = []
Xs = []
Ys = []
Zs = []

with open(filename) as gout:
    final_optimized_geometry = False
    for line in gout:
        if 'FINAL OPTIMIZED GEOMETRY' in line:
            final_optimized_geometry = True
        elif 'PRIMITIVE CELL - CENTRING CODE' in line:
            if final_optimized_geometry:
                volume = line.split()
                print volume
                print volume[7]
                volume = line.split()[7]
                VOLUMES.append(volume)

        elif ' CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC CELL (V' in line:
            if final_optimized_geometry:
                print 'gout.next() =', gout.next()
                done = gout.next()
                print 'done =', done
                p0 = done.split()[0]
                p2 = done.split()[2]

#               p0, p2 = done.split()[0:3:2]

                P0.append(p0)
                P2.append(p2)
        elif 'COORDINATES IN THE CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC CELL' in line:
            if final_optimized_geometry:
                gout.next()
                gout.next()
                while True:
                    line = gout.next()
                    atomdata = line.split()
                    if not atomdata:
                        break
                    if atomdata[1] != 'T':
                        continue
                    atomicnumber = atomdata[2]
                    x, y, z = atomdata[4:7]
                    ATOMIC_NUMBERS.append(atomicnumber)
                    Xs.append(x)
                    Ys.append(y)
                    Zs.append(z)
                final_optimized_geometry = False



print 'VOLUMES = ', VOLUMES
print 'P0 = ', P0
print 'P2 = ', P2
print 'Xs = ', Xs
print 'Ys = ', Ys
print 'Zs = ', Zs
print 'ATOMIC_NUMBERS = ', ATOMIC_NUMBERS
```

In which:

**1)** Because the next line after last atom (10th atom in this example) is an empty line,

```
                    if not atomdata:
                        break
```

will always stop when `atomdata` is empty. In other words, this will always stop when empty line, i.e. when the list of atoms has ended. Hence, this would allow to avoid the `while 'T = ATOM BELONGING TO THE ASYMMETRIC UNIT' not in line:` statement.

A similar statement would be to say:

```
                    if  atomdata:   
                        continue
```

However, for some reason I don't understand, this is not capable of interpreting non-blank lines as the only ones to be analized. Why?

**2)** This part of the code:

```
                if atomdata[1] != 'T':
                    continue
                atomicnumber = atomdata[2]
                x, y, z = atomdata[4:7]
                ATOMIC_NUMBERS.append(atomicnumber)
                Xs.append(x)
                Ys.append(y)
                Zs.append(z)
```

could also be stated as:

```
              if atomdata[1] == 'T':
                  atomicnumber = atomdata[2]
                  x, y, z = atomdata[4:7]
                  ATOMIC_NUMBERS.append(atomicnumber)
                  Xs.append(x)
                  Ys.append(y)
                  Zs.append(z)
```

Comment: If we come across a line with only whitespace (an empty line), `atomdata` will be an empty list. Accessing atomdata[1] raises the `IndexError`, since 1 is an invalid index for an empty list.

Be careful with your code, since you are issuing a `break` when `atomdata` is empty, meaning that your parser will stop at the first empty line, which you didn't want before (it will only check the first ten atoms then).

`final_optimized_geometry` is a flag to remember if we are inside a FINAL OPTIMIZED GEOMETRY block or not. It's very important to set it back to False when we leave those blocks.

Comment: @Bart Van Loon Thank you very much for this :). I totally agree that `atomdata` is an empty line when reaching the next line to the 10th atom. Hence, I can now understand the use of `if not atomdata: break`. Two things: **1)** Note that you could also use `if atomdata and atomdata[1] != 'T':`. **2)** Indeed, the space after the 10th atom breaks the `atomdata` extraction, and is an advantage that would avoid the use of the `'T = ATOM BELONGING TO THE ASYMMETRIC UNIT'` marker in your code.

Comment: @Bart Van Loon Please see updated answer where I question two types of `if` loops.

Comment: @Bart Van Loon I also understand the importance to set `final_optimized_geometry` back to `False` when we leave the block. But, why is this then not necessary in the upper blocks? (see updated answer)

Comment: Because the end of the upper blocks don't spell the end of the encompassing FINAL OPTIMIZED GEOMETRY block. This is perhaps a brittle part of the parser, in that it assumes that the volume and p data always appears before the atom data.

As for your other question, you're doing the exact opposite now. `continue` in fact doesn't merely continue as you seem to infer, but instead starts back at the beginning of the loop. You can leave out the continue and flip the if-conditional (`if atomdata [1] == 'T':`), but my personal preference lies with shorter if statement blocks.

Comment: @Bart Van Loon Thanks, I understood now. I have thought of an alternative for your `if not atomdata` statement. Please see updated answer, the **1)** point. Thanks a lot.

Comment: As I said before: `continue` does NOT continue the flow of statements but rather restarts the loop from the top. So `if atomdata: continue` effectively means skipping over every non-empty line.

Running the script step by step in `pudb` will help you understand every detail about it.